# Axis2 web service invocation error

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

**I tried to create a simple tester for my service and I get this exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: An access occurred that is not valid.
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.RobustOutOnlyAxisOperation$RobustOutOnlyOperationClient.handleResponse(RobustOutOnlyAxisOperation.java:91)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at pinservice.PinOperationStub.changePin(PinOperationStub.java:496)
    at pinservice.PinOperationTester.main(PinOperationTester.java:22)
```

**any help on troubleshooting this error or thoughts on why this happens ?**

Answer (score 0):

It is an incorrect use of message receiver (in-out and in-only). Make sure to update services.xml file with correct configuration. More details available in below link with simple example.

http://www.developer.com/services/article.php/3613896/Writing-an-Axis2-Service-from-Scratch.htm